# I want to throttle video capture frame rate in AVCapture framework

Tags: ios, accessibility, avcapturesession

I am trying to throttle my video capture framerate for my application, as I have found that it is impacting VoiceOver performance.

At the moment, it captures frames from the video camera, and then processes the frames using OpenGL routines as quickly as possible.   I would like to set a specific framerate in the capture process.

I was expecting to be able to do this by using videoMinFrameDuration or minFrameDuration, but this seems to make no difference to performance.  Any ideas?

```
    NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices) 
{
    if ([device position] == AVCaptureDevicePositionBack) 
    {
        backFacingCamera = device;
                    //  SET SOME OTHER PROPERTIES
    }
}


// Create the capture session
captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

// Add the video input  
NSError *error = nil;
videoInput = [[[AVCaptureDeviceInput alloc] initWithDevice:backFacingCamera error:&error] autorelease];

// Add the video frame output   
videoOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
[videoOutput setAlwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames:YES];

[videoOutput setVideoSettings:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA] forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey]];
[videoOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];



// Start capturing
if([backFacingCamera supportsAVCaptureSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080])
{
    [captureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080]; 
    captureDeviceWidth = 1920; 
    captureDeviceHeight = 1080;
    #if defined(VA_DEBUG)
    NSLog(@"Video AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080");
    #endif
}
else  do some fall back stuff

// If you wish to cap the frame rate to a known value, such as 15 fps, set 
// minFrameDuration.
AVCaptureConnection *conn = [videoOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
if (conn.supportsVideoMinFrameDuration)
    conn.videoMinFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1,2);
else
    videoOutput.minFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1,2);


if ([captureSession canAddInput:videoInput]) 
    [captureSession addInput:videoInput];


if ([captureSession canAddOutput:videoOutput])
    [captureSession addOutput:videoOutput];

if (![captureSession isRunning])
    [captureSession startRunning];
```

Any ideas?  Am I missing something?   Is this the best way to throttle?

```
AVCaptureConnection *conn = [videoOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
if (conn.supportsVideoMinFrameDuration)
    conn.videoMinFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1,2);
else
    videoOutput.minFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1,2);
```

Comment: I was not clear in my original message.   The minFrameDuration methods don't seem to do anything, it is not reducing the framerate.  I am building against ios 4.3 target with an ios 5.0 SDK.

Answer (score 12):

Mike Ullrich's answer worked up until ios 7.  These two methods are unfortunately deprecated in ios7.  You have to set the `activeVideo{Min|Max}FrameDuration` on the AVCaptureDevice itself.  Something like:

```
int fps                             = 30;  // Change this value
AVCaptureDevice *device             = ...; // Get the active capture device
[device lockForConfiguration:nil];
[device setActiveVideoMinFrameDuration:CMTimeMake(1, fps)];
[device setActiveVideoMaxFrameDuration:CMTimeMake(1, fps)];
[device unlockForConfiguration];
```

Answer (score 3):

Turns out you need to set both videoMinFrameDuration and videoMaxFrameDuration for either one to work.

eg:

```
[conn setVideoMinFrameDuration:CMTimeMake(1,1)];
[conn setVideoMaxFrameDuration:CMTimeMake(1,1)];
```